# There are 6 equilateral triangles within a hexagon, given an x,y coordinate, how can I determine which equilateral triangle the coordinate is in?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon

I am creating a game in 3D Virtual world.  I have created a hexagon using 6 equilateral triangles numbered t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6.

Given an x,y coordinate within the hexagon, what formula can I use to determine which triangle the point is in?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have the 6 triangles, why not check each one? 6 checks is not a lot at all.

Comment: Ok, I found a mathematical solutition here using convex hulls: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInterior.html

Comment: But now need to code it - anyone have a php solution?

Comment: Ok, think I found an answer here for the algorithm: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html

Comment: Transform your coordinates from (*x*, *y*) to (*x* + ½√3 *y*, *y*). Then determining which triangle your point belongs to is easy. (I would have added an answer with diagrams and code, but for some reason the question was closed.)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your (x,y) coordinates to polar coordinates.

You have 6 equilateral triangles in your hexagon, so each "triangle frontier" is separated by Pi/3 radians. So when you have your theta angle, you can guess which triangle you are in.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the point is inside the hexagon, and you know how the triangles are oriented, you can calculate the angle of the point with respect to the center:

```
atan2((y-yc)/(x-xc)).
```

If `x == xc` the angle is either +90 or -90 degrees (PI/2 or -PI/2 radians) depending on y.

(If you don't have `atan2`, you need to check the quadrant manually: see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates )

Point-inside-triangle testing (A, B and C are the vertices of the triangle represented as (x,y)):

```
// Compute vectors        
v0 = C - A             // Which means v0[x] = C[x] - A[x], v0[y] = C[y] - A[y]
v1 = B - A             // etc.
v2 = P - A

// Compute dot products
dot00 = dot(v0, v0)    // dot(a,b) is a[x]*b[x]+a[y]*b[y]
dot01 = dot(v0, v1)
dot02 = dot(v0, v2)
dot11 = dot(v1, v1)
dot12 = dot(v1, v2)

// Compute barycentric coordinates (faster using inverse, but clearer this way)

denom = (dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01)
u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) / Denom
v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) / Denom

// Check if point is in triangle
return (u >= 0) && (v >= 0) && (u + v < 1)

from http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html
```

Remember that you can save 50-66% time by saving the calculations: all your triangles have two vertices in common. Also you can only test *five* of them, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by checking if the point lies on the same side of the lines forming one triangle. Continue checking for six of your triangles and find whichever fits.

Find equations of the lines forming a triangle and put the co-ordinates of the point under check in each equation (make sure the'x' of each equation has got the same sign). If the resulting values have 2 same and 1 different sign, then the point is inside the triangle.

Practically, in your case, you will have 9 equations of lines. If you take the origin at the center of your hexagon, the equations of the line will be very easy. Just find those 9 values and search for 3 such values satisfying the previously mentioned condition. The parent equations of these three values constitute the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the point should be inside the triangle whose vertices are closed to the point in average.

The center vertex can be ignore as it is shared by all triangles.

If you have the remanding vertexes sorted by distance to the point (6 in total as they are shared by adjacent triangles), the triangle you are looking for is the one whose most distant vertex is found first in the list traversing in ascending order.